# Что за метка [timeout]?

Tags: поддержка, метки

Я недавно увидел метку [timeout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timeout) (63 вопроса), у неё нет описания. По ней в основном задают вопросы про какой-то таймаут ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1522615/)), но в тоже время используют в другом совершенно не понятном контексте ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1536849/)).

Так что же это за метка?

Comment: timeout - предельное время ожидания. В первом случае нужно что-то завершить при превышении времени, во втором - видимо решение не проходит проверку по времени выполнения. В целом, я бы выпилил ее везде.